# How to push an element to the left of a div and another element to the right of that same div?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have this long bar div and 2 pieces of text inside the innerHTML of that div.

How would I make one of the elements hug the left side of the div and one hug the right side?

I thought `float:left;` and `float: right;` would have worked but only one of them can work at a time.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: float is not for aligning purpose but floating an element within a text-block. use flexbox or grid instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shared any code, so it's hard to know what you've attempted so far..

You mention you've set the text via innerHTML, but if you're instead able to actually edit the markup itself, then this left/right text split can easily be achieved by using flexbox. Here, I've sepearted the items with the [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) property:

```css
.longDiv {
background: orange;
width: 300px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="longDiv">
  <p>left text</p>
  <p>right text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple floats in one container.  See this example.  I generally make sure the floats are defined "first", before the other content of the container.  The order of the elements does make a difference on how they render.

```css
.long {
  width: 200px;
  height: 2em;
  
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  border: solid thin black;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="long box">
  <span class="left box">L</span>
  <span class="right box">R</span>

  Sample text.
</div>
```

Comment: Do not answer on question that miss details and clarity such as debugging details. answering such questions make it harder to remove those question with the automated systems

Comment: This question was perfectly clear to me, so I provided an answer.

Comment: its not about if it is clear to you. You simply should not just answer any low-quality question. The question does not meet the guidelines and provide insufficient debugging details. as such it should be removed to keep SO on track. If we keep every low quality question we will not find the suefull questions anymore. Answering on those question even if they are easy, is just unecessary reputation hunting that makes the deletion process harder.

Comment: I guess that does make some sense. But it does leave a large number of people in the dark because I'm sure to them it was an important question, otherwise they would not have been asking it. It would be almost like google giving you a blank page of results if it's AI engine deemed the search terms of being too low of quality. Hm... that does give you something to think about... only a select percentage of users will get answers to their questions.  That could also explain why questions I have asked in the past went unanswered because answering is tied more to quality, not to providing answers.

Comment: we have plenty duplicates for that around here. Does not resolve the initial issue though. The OP has all chances to edit the question to meet the guidelines (that he even has been linked to).